# Benefits of using Auth0 over PassportJS?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, passport.js, auth0

Anyone have any insight as to why Auth0 is a better choice for authentication/authorization in a NodeJS Ecosystem?

Comment: Auth0 as opposed to? Generally, in security, you want to decouple your app from the security function (be it authN, authZ, other)... You want to use a framework. That could mean using a service e.g. Auth0 (known as an IDaaS - identity as a service) or using the framework your language gives you (PassportJS) or using OS e.g. WS02, Gluu, or more.

Comment: What Auth0 gives you, though, is a service meaning they provide SLAs, they provide enhancements, and they provide support. Frameworks typically don't do that. You're responsible for your own operations.